# json_encode not accepting column or special charters or white space

Tags: php, json

I am trying to edit data through json, but whenever I use json with special charters on any column it does not accept it giving the error, when the json is not correct, as

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in
>   {"id":"21","question":"Participant Scoring Organizers can edit their
>   participants
>
> **The data which I want to edit is like this**
>
> Participant Scoring Organizers can edit their participants' scores at
>   any time and regardless of the event (@status)

All the content is coming from a database table in the form of an array like this

> Array ( [id] => 21 [question] => Participant Scoring Organizers can
>   edit their participants' scores at any time and regardless of the
>   event (@status)

I am converting the array form content in the form of json using the `json_encode()` function but its not working showing the above error

I have tried

```
data-json='<?php echo json_encode($ques,true); ?>'
```

and

```
data-json='<?php echo json_encode($ques,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); ?>'
```

and

```
data-json="<?php echo json_encode($ques,true); ?>"
```

and

```
data-json=\"<?php echo json_encode($ques,true); ?>\"
```

When I click on the link I get to the edit page but the json_encode does not work. Can someone tell me why its not accepting special charters and column or sometime white space?

```
<td><a href="#/pencil-square-o" class="edit_faq option_icon"
data-json='<?php echo json_encode($ques,true); ?>'
data-block="athlete_form_block" data-form="faq_form" ><i  class="fa
fa-edit"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape your HTML attribute with `htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')` like so:

```
 <td><a href="#/pencil-square-o" class="edit_faq option_icon"
     data-json='<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($ques), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>'
     data-block="athlete_form_block" data-form="faq_form" ><i  class="fa
     fa-edit"></i></a>
```

Comment: thankyou very much, sir your answer is right its most useful for me thankyou once again sir